# In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, I can not set index of tabbar

Tags: ios, tabbar

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    if (condition) {
        UITabBarController *tabbar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        [tabbar setSelectedIndex:4];
    }
    ...
}
```

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, I can not set selected index of tabbar.
UITabbarController is initial viewController in my project.

I want to set another tabbar index for special condition, when users launch my app.

I have tested ios7, ios8.
Is there any other way?

Comment: What is `if (condition)` ? that's probably whats stopping the process

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem in your code, is that there's no identified UITabBarController... If you're using storyboard it's easy to make this connection -

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
UITabBarController *tabBarViewController = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"]; //Set this identifier in the storyboard
[tabBarViewController setSelectedIndex:1];
```